# server detect loss of network in javascript

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io, raspberry-pi, webserver

Running a raspberry pi server thats hosts a simple page.
Is there an event (preferably in socket.io or express) that will notice that the pi has lost network connection.

have tried this server side

```
io.on('connect', function(socket){
 console.log("a user connected");
 socket.on('disconnect'), function(){
  console.log("user disconnected");
 });
 socket.on('connect_error', function(){
   console.log("server disconnected")
 });
});
```

based on the code from http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

it does notice if the client pc closes the webpage but unfortunately

```
'connect_error'
```

does not notice when i pull the wireless out of the pi or turn it off on my pc.

my server is supposed to be driving motors so it needs to know when its not receiving commands from the client and stop, though responding to server loss of network is the only specified requirement.

If i have to i know i could write a periodic check to look at the network state or how long its been since the last command, but it really feels like something that should be encapsulated in an event somewhere. or have some way of dealing with it asynchronously.

Comment: You may want to implement a watchdog timer to ensure communication with the client, regardless of status of the network (e.g. network up, client down).

Comment: yeah you might be right, someone going afk could be just as bad as losing network connection and checking for that would definitely have the same effect.